# React Native - I cannot use Drawer Navigation in a method

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

I created a react-native project and there is a login screen in it. I use drawer navigation in this project however it works partially.

I can switch to any page I want from the side menu. Or I can stroll between the pages via the onPress method I wrote in login screen. But I can't redirect to main page after login. Or when clicked on a record in a list, I can't switch to that record's detail page using its parameters.

I want switch to page after I logged in on loginActions.js, loginSuccess method. It is possible or how can i do this?

I am beginner about react native so i am waiting for your helps.

Sorry for my bad English.

My LoginForm.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser} from './actions/loginActions';
import {Button, Card, CardSection, Spinner, CustomHeader} from './components/componentIndex';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import _ from 'lodash';

class LoginForm extends Component{
    clickLogin(){
const {email, password} = this.props;
this.props.loginUser({email, password});
}

drawerOpen(){
    this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen');
}

clickSignUpButton(){
    this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp');
}

adminPanel(){
    this.props.navigation.navigate('AdminPanel');
}

     addSupplierStock (s) {
    if(s == 's'){
        return 's';
    }

    }

renderButton(){
if(!this.props.loading){
return <Button onPress={this.clickLogin.bind(this)}> GİRİŞ </Button>;
}
return <Spinner size="small" />
}

 render() {
     const { inputStyle, textStyle, viewStyle } = styles;
     return (
     <View style = {{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
      <CustomHeader headerText={'Çarşı Pazar'} onPress={this.drawerOpen.bind(this)}/>
      <Text style = {textStyle}> Lütfen Giriş Yapınız.</Text>
       <Card>
         <CardSection>
           <TextInput
             placeholder="E-mail"
             style={inputStyle}
             value={this.props.email}
             onChangeText={email => this.props.emailChanged(email)}
           />
         </CardSection>

         <CardSection>
         <TextInput
           secureTextEntry
           placeholder="Şifre"
           style={inputStyle}
           value={this.props.password}
           onChangeText={password => this.props.passwordChanged(password)}
         />
         </CardSection>

         <CardSection>
            {this.renderButton()}
         </CardSection>

           <CardSection>
               <Button onPress={this.adminPanel.bind(this)}> Şimdilik Admin Panel </Button>
           </CardSection>
       </Card>

 <Card>
  <CardSection>
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <View  style={{width: 200, height: 50}}>
        <Button onPress={this.clickSignUpButton.bind(this)}> Kayıt Ol </Button>
        </View>

        <View style={{width: 200, height: 50}}>
        <Button onPress={this.asd.bind(this)}> Şifremi Unuttum </Button>
        </View>
        </View>
         </CardSection>
 </Card>

       </View>
     );
   }
}

 const styles = {
     textStyle: {
         alignSelf: 'center',
         color: '#007aff',
         fontSize: 16,
         fontWeight: '600',
         paddingTop: 10,
         paddingBottom: 10
       },
       inputStyle: {
           paddingRight: 5,
           paddingLeft: 5,
           fontSize: 18,
           flex: 1
       },
      };

const mapStateToProps = ({loginResponse}) => {
    const {email, password, loading} = loginResponse;
    return {
        email: 'test@test.com',
        password: '123456',
        loading
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser})(LoginForm);
```

My loginReducers.js:

```
import {EMAIL_CHANGED, PASSWORD_CHANGED, LOGIN_USER, LOGIN_FAIL, LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS} from "../actions/types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    loading: false
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case EMAIL_CHANGED:
            return {...state, email: action.payload};
        case PASSWORD_CHANGED:
            return {...state, password: action.payload};
        case LOGIN_USER:
            return {...state, loading: true};
        case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
            return {...state, loading: false};
        case LOGIN_FAIL:
            return {...state, loading: false};
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

My loginActions.js:

```
import {EMAIL_CHANGED, PASSWORD_CHANGED, LOGIN_USER, LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAIL} from "./types";
import {NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import SupplierMainPage from "../supplier/SupplierMainPage";

export const emailChanged = (email) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: EMAIL_CHANGED,
            payload: email
        });
    };
};

export const passwordChanged = (password) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: PASSWORD_CHANGED,
            payload: password
        });
    };
};

export const loginUser = ({email, password}) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({type: LOGIN_USER});
      console.log('Logging In: ' + email);
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(user => loginSuccess(dispatch, user))
          .catch(() => loginFail(dispatch));
};
};

const loginSuccess = (dispatch, user) => {
    console.log('Success');
    dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload: user
    });
};

const loginFail = (dispatch) => {
    console.log('Fail');
    dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_FAIL
    });
};
```

My Router.js:

```
export default DrawerNavigator({
    Login: {
        screen: LoginForm
    },
    SignUp: {
        screen: SignUpFrom
    },
    SupplierMainPage: {
        screen: SupplierMainPage
    },
    AddStock: {
        screen: AddStockForm
    },
    CustomerOrder: {
        screen: CustomerOrder
    },
    AdminPanel: {
        screen: AdminPanel
    },
    MarketForm: {
        screen: MarketForm
    },
    UserForm: {
        screen: UserForm
    },
    MarketSupplierRelationForm: {
        screen: MarketSupplierRelationForm
    },
    SupplierStockRelationForm: {
        screen: SupplierStockRelationForm
    }
}, {
    contentComponent: SideMenu,
    drawerWidth: 300
});
```

And my App.js, render method:

```
render() {
     const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
     return (
         <Provider store={store}>
             <Router />
         </Provider>
     );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation', and then if you have dispatch, you can do

```
const loginSuccess = (dispatch, user) => {
    dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS' , payload: user });
};
```